# NSURLSessionDataTask "System group container for..."

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios10

So, Hello new Apple iOS10. And million new bugs in it!

I'm using NSURLSessionDataTask to get information from server.

My code is:

```
NSLog(@"To URL %@", request.URL);
NSURLSession *session = ...

[session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error){ 
if (error) 
   {
     NSLog(@"error:%@",error);
   }
});
```

On log in Client I see:

> URL http://192.168.0.101:8084/?res=yes
>
> :[MC] System group container
>   for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is
>   /private/var/containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
>
> :[MC] Reading from public effective user settings.

And than Timedout Error

> :XPC connection interrupted
>
> : __27-[_UIRemoteKeyboards proxy]_block_invoke Failed to access remote
>   service: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4097 "connection to
>   service named com.apple.UIKit.KeyboardManagement.hosted"
>   UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=connection to service named
>   com.apple.UIKit.KeyboardManagement.hosted}
>
> :Error:Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1004 "Could not connect to
>   the server." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x170249f00 {Error
>   Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1004 "(null)"
>   UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=51, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}},
>   NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://192.168.0.101:8084/?res=yes,
>   NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://192.168.0.101:8084/?res=yes,
>   _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=51, NSLocalizedDescription=Could not connect to the server.}

What is that? Its appears right after Xcode update from 7→8!

Is somebody know whats going on?

P.S. :
My "App Transport Security Settings" is set to "Allow Arbitrary Loads" as YES

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Logs from server is empty

Comment: did you find an answer to this?